# How to suppress Approval in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

My code works in previous versions 2018 r2 and earlier.
I use `dontApprove` field. I tried doing this with 2019 R1, it is not working. How can I achieve it on 2019 R1.

Thanks!

Comment: did you read the release notes if this field has been dropped ?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?  What graph/screen?  Are you trying to always suppress or under certain conditions?  And can you provide any code sample for frame of reference.The field is still present in several graphs of 2019R2 in standard code.  In SOOrderEntry, it is a formula field on the SOOrder table and is set based on whether approval is enabled for the order type.